# Setting absolute point size for geom_point with scale_size_area

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `ggplot2` and `scale_size_area()`, how to I make the point size for `area = 0.5` correspond to the size of a default point (`size = 0.5`)?

Here is a simple repex showing that this is not the default behavior. I would like for the black and red points to have the same size at the middle point (where `area = 0.5`):

```r
ggplot(data.frame(area = seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 17), y = 1), aes(x = area, y = y)) + 
    geom_point(aes(size = area), color = "red") +  # Area point
    geom_point() +  # Default point
    scale_size_area("size_area")
```

[image]

I have tried and failed with `area = area / 2` and `scale_size_area(rescaler = NULL)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play around with the `range` and `limits` arguments within `scale_size` to get something closer to what you're looking for:

```
ggplot(data.frame(area = seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 17), y = 1), aes(x = area, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = area), color = "red") +  # Area point
  geom_point() +  # Default point
  scale_size("size_area", range = c(-20, 10))
```

[image]

EDIT:

Since that's a little hacky and not scalable, the better way to do this is to first figure out what the default point size is:

```
default_size <- ggplot2:::check_subclass("point", "Geom")$default_aes$size
default_size
[1] 1.5
```

It should be 1.5, unless you've manually changed the defaults. Now we can rebuild the plot and figure out how the size aesthetic is currently being mapped to area:

```
df <- data.frame(area = seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 17), y = 1)

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = area, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = area), color = "red") +  # Area point
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_area()

g2 <- ggplot_build(g)

g2$data[[1]] %>%
  select(x, size)

x     size
1  0.0000 0.000000
2  0.0625 1.500000
3  0.1250 2.121320
4  0.1875 2.598076
5  0.2500 3.000000
6  0.3125 3.354102
7  0.3750 3.674235
8  0.4375 3.968627
9  0.5000 4.242641
10 0.5625 4.500000
11 0.6250 4.743416
12 0.6875 4.974937
13 0.7500 5.196152
14 0.8125 5.408327
15 0.8750 5.612486
16 0.9375 5.809475
17 1.0000 6.000000
```

The relationship is size = 6*sqrt(x). Why 6? Because the [scale_size_area](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_size.html) has a default `max_size` of 6. So, to make it so the x-value of 0.5 maps to 1.5 size, we have to solve the above equation for a new `max_size`, and we get 1.5/sqrt(0.5).

To automate this, we can do the following:

```
default_size_val <- 0.5
max_size <- default_size/(sqrt(default_size_val))

ggplot(df, aes(x = area, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = area), color = "red") +  # Area point
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_area(max_size = max_size)
```

[image]

Comment: I want to scale according to area - not radius. Also, the solution should work for any (positive) range of areas so iterating towards hard-coded solutions is not an option, unfortunately.